# Rigidbody2D.MovePosition cause lags in physic, for example, gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tested and this script cause lags in physic. It seems to me that it call physic not per 0,2 seconds, but much-much more rarely and because of this object falling much more slower.

Here's a gif to demonstrate what happens: The purple one without script, the blue one with script.

[image: GIF.]

So how can I fix that?

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(0, 0);

    public float movementSpeed = 10f;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * movementSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) overrules the movement => don't use it if you want physics (force) based movements and reaction to collisions etc.

You want to use the input only for the horizontal movement but use physics for the vertical. `MovePosition` affects both directions.

Try directly setting the [`Rigidbody.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) instead

```
private void Update()
{
    // Get the current velocity
    var velocity = rb.velocity;

    // Only overwrite the x velocity
    // since the velocity is only applied in the FixedUpdate anyway
    // there is no problem setting this already in Update
    // And since it is the velocity which is already frame-rate independent
    // there is no need for Time.deltaTime
    velocity.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * movementSpeed;

    // Assign back the changed velocity
    rb.velocity = velocity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the logic of your code if I understand what you want to do.

You seem to be moving in a vertical fashion yet only have the x component of your `vector2` from the horizontal input.

```
new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0);
```

If the GIF you attached, the object is just in freefall, so that would be a vertical drop, or the y component of the `vector2`, which you are setting to 0. Think of this as (x,y) or (move horizontally (left/right), move vertically (up/down)).

I would change the above line to:

```
movement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
```

You can now move vertically using vertical input. Something else which would not cause your issue, but is mentioned on the [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) docs is to mark your `Rigidbody2D` as `Interpolate`. It is the bottom field in the `Rigidbody2D` component labeled `Interpolate`, set it from `None` to `Interpolate`.

The reason your object is moving slowly without any input is because you still have your `Gravity Scale` on the `Rigidbody` set to 1 instead of 0. If you are trying to simulate gravity with this script, add the vertical component to your input vector and set the `Gravity Scale` field on the `Rigidbody` to 0. The `MovePosition` is fighting the current gravity attempting to affect it.

Comment: No, if i understand you right. I need gravity in my game and this script should affect only horizontal movemnt. but not the vertical.

Comment: Then you do not want to use `MovePosition` as it will overwrite the basic gravity. You do not understand what it does. Swap out your movement for something like derHugo recommended.